# How to improve wireless throughput on RPi 3 b+ in AP mode?

Tags: wifi, pi-3b+

I've upgraded from 3 to 3 b+ in hopes of improving throughput on wireless network (using built-in wireless chip as AP and wired connection on the other end). I've configured it to work in 802.11ac mode, and my laptop sees it as such with pretty reasonable signal level (-50 dBm signal and -99 dBm noise), but RPi still reports speed as 54 Mbps (my other AC router reports speed as 234 Mbps) and actual speed does not exceed `20 Mbps` (tested with iperf3 -t 30 -P 30). Which is even worse than if I use my old 3 in 802.11n mode.

How can I improve Wi-Fi speed on my RPi?

Below is my hostapd.conf. OS is headless raspbian/debiab stretch (9.4 fully updated).

```
ssid=<redacted>
wpa_passphrase=<redacted>

country_code=US

interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211

wpa=2
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP

logger_syslog=-1
logger_syslog_level=0
logger_stdout=-1
logger_stdout_level=0

hw_mode=a
ieee80211n=1
require_ht=1
ieee80211ac=1
require_vht=1
ieee80211d=1
ieee80211h=0

ht_capab=[HT40+][SHORT-GI-20][SHORT-GI-40][DSSS_CK-40][MAX-AMSDU-3839]
vht_capab=[MAX-MPDU-3895][SHORT-GI-80][SU-BEAMFORMEE]

vht_oper_chwidth=1
channel=36
vht_oper_centr_freq_seg0_idx=42

wmm_enabled=0
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
```

Answer (score 2):

3B+ works okay-ish with 2.4 range. It works better with 5G (I could do 10MB/s+)

This is my hostapd.conf, that works well as you wanted.
 (comment/uncomment parts detailed to switch between 5Ghz and 2.4ghz).

```
# This is the name of the WiFi interface we configured above
interface=wlan0
country_code=US
# Use the nl80211 driver with the brcmfmac driver
driver=nl80211
# Enable 802.11n
ieee80211n=1
require_ht=1
ht_capab=[MAX-AMSDU-3839][HT40+][SHORT-GI-20][SHORT-GI-40][DSSS_CCK-40]


#AC
ieee80211ac=1
require_vht=1
ieee80211d=0
ieee80211h=0

# Use the 2.4GHz band
# Comment for 5ghz
hw_mode=g
channel=1

# use 5Ghz
#hw_mode=a
#channel=36
#vht_capab=[MAX-AMSDU-3839][SHORT-GI-80]
#vht_oper_chwidth=1
#vht_oper_centr_freq_seg0_idx=42

# Enable WMM
wmm_enabled=1

# Enable 40MHz channels with 20ns guard interval
#ht_capab=[HT40][SHORT-GI-20][DSSS_CCK-40]
#ht_capab=[HT20][SHORT-GI-20][RX-STBC1]
```

Comment: This is fine, and hopefully you recognize the difference.  In the future, direct questions and answers **only**, no extended sidebars, no sniping.   If you want something else, try reddit or facebook. So again: When you have [more reputation points](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges), you can add comments to other people's posts. Take [the tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand better how the site works.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably no model of Pi that is a good choice as an AP, especially considering for the same money (board + SD card + power supply) you can get an actual dedicated AP, likely with better wifi hardware in it. If you have your reasons though, fair enough. The numbers you are getting seem roughly equivalent to this @2.4 Ghz:

[Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+ WiFi Performance](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=raspberry-pi3bplus-wifi&num=2)

Which also makes it clear if you want a speed improvement and you aren't using 5Ghz (I dunno if this is implicit in your hostapd config), switch to 5 GHhz, or else be happy with ~50 Mbps.

Comment: Channel 36 is explicitly makes it 5G (as this is 5G channel range), but the performance in general seems to be even worse than previous model that’s based off another chip. Generally RPi should be capable of much better performance. My wild guess is that it is the driver.

Comment: I actually have reasonably good AP. I just need to run a software on a router that I constantly modify and test. So as long as it works in general I am okay. But I can’t test software under heavy load without good throughput.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow on your config RPi 3b+ wifi speed improves to **~100 Mbit/s** when **wmm_enabled=1**.

Usable but still unstable: After every couple seconds it drops to ~20 Mbit/s. From watching *hostapd -d hostapd.conf* output I guess drops are related to frequencies scan events:

> wlan0: nl80211: Scan trigger
>
> nl80211: Drv Event 34 (NL80211_CMD_NEW_SCAN_RESULTS) received for wlan0